# Django: Risks in handling data directly from request.POST["item"]

Tags: python, django, security, django-models, django-forms

Sometimes I have a form that is a bit complicated in logic, and needs validation beyond just type checking or regex, so I end up handling data directly from `request.POST['item']`, like:

- `datetime.strptime(request.POST['item'], FORMAT)`
- `MyModel.objects.filter(name=request.POST['item2']`

As far as I know, the first example would throw an exception at worst, so no security problems, and for the second example, the Django ORM would prevent SQLi. Is that correct?

I also have regex in the URLConf, so I guess it would be safe to handle the data taken from the URL in views.py because URLConf already validated it with regex, right?

Comment: I would change it for request.POST.get('item'), since you'll avoid IndexError exceptions. Also you can use the "get" function to set a default value in case 'item' won't be present

Comment: If you think that form validation is "just type checking or regex" then you either failed to read the fine manual or didn't provide good enough examples of your "complicated logic". Not to say directly using POST items is necessarily wrong - forms are mostly a wrapper around POST (or GET FWIW) and sometimes it can come in your way or is just not needed - but I have yet to see a case where the use case for not using forms was "too complex validation"...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers There are many examples if you took the trouble to think of one. I'm not into explaining my use cases, I want an answer for my specific question: about security.

Comment: @Orca, I agree with your "please don't question my use cases" stance since that also drives me crazy.  But now I'm curious because I can't think of any (I know, because my clean_ functions can get pretty hairy :-)

Comment: @RobOsborne Sometimes I need to validate some data and certain conditions with external websites (a strange business case, I know). Django forms don't do that kind of validation ;)

Comment: Tada!  I should have thought of that since URLField had to deprecate the validation option for exactly this case :-)

Comment: @RobOsborne Huh? What functionality was deprecated? I'm intrigued.

Comment: Some of the reasoning is discussed here https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2011/sep/09/security-releases-issued/ but in general you don't want this kind of stuff happening behind the scenes.

Comment: @Orca and RobOsborne: asking for more about the concrete use case is the best way to help people asking about "what they think is the solution" instead of asking about the actual problem they're trying to solve, and from experience when the question is weird chances are the OP is not going in the right direction. Orca: wrt/ the "validate some data and certain conditions with external websites", yes Django forms can do these kind of validation - or more exactly it's very easy to plug whatever validation code you want in a form before, after or in place of the default validation for your field.

Comment: NB : once again I don't mean you _have_ to use forms, just that I still wait to see any validation logic that could not be implemented at the form level...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  If these cases were NOT secure they would be security issues and be patched quickly if discovered.